# how to use cookie in telegram Bot Api with php?

Tags: php, cookies, bots, telegram

I tried use cookie in php file of telegram webhook, but don't work!
My code is:

```
$cookie_name = "tlgrm_command";
$cookie_value = "code";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400*2), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

But `$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]` is `null`!

Comment: That‘s most likely because it does not make sense to use cookies in a _webhook_ scenario in the first place.

Comment: how to store a variable in telegram bot api?

Comment: thanks @CBore . how to use session for store variable in webhook?

Comment: Why would this need a session?

Comment: a send multi command to user and wait for respond in webhook. I need to know what was the command.

Comment: generally i need to store a var for ever user in webhook. what's the solution?

Comment: Storing data “in the webhook” makes no sense whatsoever. Store it at your end. You get the user id via the webhook, so you can put the data into your database/text file/whatever under that id.

Comment: @AminRusta Cookie doesn't make sense in telegram webhooks. You need to store the chatid and actions in your php in a hashtable, key value store or database. Basically there is no data store (I mean cookies) on the user side, and everything needs to be stored on the serverside by you. When you receive a request you may look up the chat id in your database and see what the past actions were.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to:
Use a session.
It has higher security and your problems will be solved this way